# Проблема с плеером Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from playsound import playsound

def sound1(path):
    path = r'C:/music'
    for sound in os.listdir(path):
        playsound('%s/%s' % (path, sound)) 

    def quit():
        root1.quit()

    root1 = Tk()
    btn1 = Button(text="Play", command=sound1)
    btn2 = Button(text="Quit", command=quit)
    btn1.pack()
    btn2.pack()
    root1.mainloop()
```

> TypeError: sound1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

В чём причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию `sound1()` с аргументом `path`, однако аргумента в неё не передаёте. Попробуйте:

```
def sound1():
    path = r'C:/music'
    for sound in os.listdir(path):
        playsound('%s/%s' % (path, sound))
```